# node-ffi:call c lib with callback function

Tags: node-ffi

I want call a c lib,the .h file like this:

```
typedef void (*ConnectEventCallBack)(int iBaseID, int iMode, const char* sInfo);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void SetConnectEventCallBack(ConnectEventCallBack cb);
```

in node-ffi,how to define the function and use it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way:

```js
var ffi = require('ffi');

// Interface into the native lib
var libname = ffi.Library('./libname', {
  'SetConnectEventCallBack': ['void', ['pointer']]
});

// Callback from the native lib back into js
var callback = ffi.Callback('void', ['int', 'int', 'string'],
  function(iBaseId, iMode, sInfo) {

    console.log("iBaseId: ", iBaseId);
    console.log("iMode: ", iMode);
    console.log("sInfo: ", sInfo);

  });

console.log("registering the callback");
libname.SetConnectEventCallBack(callback);
console.log('Done');

// Make an extra reference to the callback pointer to avoid GC
process.on('exit', function() {
  callback
});
```

The C library can call this callback using another thread. It is safe. In this case the javascript function for the callback will be fired in the main event loop and the caller thread will wait until the call returns. The return value is passed to the caller thread too.

Note that you need to keep a reference to the callback pointer returned by `ffi.Callback` in some way to avoid garbage collection.

Comment: Is there any documentation for ffi.Callback? I cannot find it and there are no examples on the node-ffi wiki on GitHub.

Comment: No, there is no documentation yet. But you can check this [example](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/blob/master/example/sqlite.js) and these [tests](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/blob/master/test/callback.js). I will add something to the tutorial.

Comment: You might want to add that the callback function will get garbage collected unless it's saved in some way. Does the "return 0" serve a purpose?

Comment: Another question, maybe I should create a "real" question?
When using node-ffi with Electron can the "lib" be inside the *.asar file? I have a sneaking suspicion that it can't, cause I get the 126 error...

Comment: You can post a bug/suggestion report in the GitHub repo. You have a duplicate comment above.

Comment: Okey, I suggest being able to use a file buffer as well as a filename. But I'll create a suggestion. Thank you. (Because it doesn't work when the dll is inside an asar archive, I tried it.)